# How to use react spring for animations

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, typescript, sass

Im trying to implement these repos in react(remix):

https://github.com/simeydotme/pokemon-cards-css

https://github.com/Maurier/vue-pokemon-cards-css

I have tried to strip back to the bare bones of the code and I am using `react-spring` for the animations but I am stuck and cant see to get it working. Heres what I have so far:

```
export const links: LinksFunction = () => {
    return [
        {
            rel: "stylesheet",
            href: styles,
        },
    ];
};

interface CardProps {
    img: string;
    name: string;
}

const round = (num: number) => Math.round(num * 100) / 100;

const Card = (props: CardProps) => {
    const {
        img,
        name,
    } = props;
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(true);
    const [frontImg, setFrontImg] = useState(img);

    const springR = { stiffness: 333, damping: 25 };
    const springD = { stiffness: 333, damping: 45 };

    const [springRotate, setSpringRotate] = useSpring(() => ({ x: 0, y: 0, config: springR }));
    const [springRotateDelta, setSpringRotateDelta] = useSpring(() => ({ x: 0, y: 0, config: springD }));

    const cardRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);
    const rotatorRef = useRef<HTMLButtonElement>(null);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (cardRef.current) {
            cardRef.current.style.setProperty('--rx', `${springRotate.x.get() + springRotateDelta.x.get()}deg`);
            cardRef.current.style.setProperty('--ry', `${springRotate.y.get() + springRotateDelta.y.get()}deg`);
        }
    }, [springRotate, springRotateDelta]);

    const interact = (e: React.MouseEvent) => {
        const $el = e.target as HTMLElement;
        const rect = $el.getBoundingClientRect();
        const absolute = {
            x: e.clientX - rect.left,
            y: e.clientY - rect.top,
        };
        const percent = {
            x: round((100 / rect.width) * absolute.x),
            y: round((100 / rect.height) * absolute.y),
        };
        const center = {
            x: percent.x - 50,
            y: percent.y - 50,
        };

        setSpringRotate({
            x: round(-(center.x / 3.5)),
            y: round(center.y / 2),
        });
    };

    const interactEnd = (e: React.MouseEvent, delay: number = 100) => {
        setTimeout(() => {
            setSpringRotate({ x: 0, y: 0 });
        }, delay);
    };

    const imageLoader = () => {
        setLoading(false);
    };

    return (
        <div
            className="card"
            ref={() => cardRef}
        >
            <div className="card__translater">
                <animated.button
                    className="card__rotator"
                    ref={() => rotatorRef}
                    onMouseMove={interact}
                    onMouseOut={interactEnd}
                    style={{ ...springRotate, ...springRotateDelta }}
                    aria-label={`Expand the Pokemon Card; ${name}.`}
                >
                    <div className="card__front">
                        <img
                            src={frontImg}
                            onLoad={imageLoader}
                            alt={`Front design of the ${name} Pokemon Card, with the stats and info around the edge`}
                        />
                    </div>
                </animated.button>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
};
```

My styles:

```
:root {
    --rx: 0deg;
    --ry: 0deg;
}

.card {
    --radius: 4.55% / 3.5%;
    transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0.1px);
    will-change: transform, visibility;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    width: 300px;
}

.card__translater,
.card__rotator {
    display: grid;
    perspective: 600px;
    transform-origin: center;
    will-change: transform;
}

.card__translater {
    width: auto;
    position: relative;
}

.card__rotator {
    transform: rotateY(var(--rx)) rotateX(var(--ry));
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
    box-shadow: 0px 10px 20px -5px black;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    outline: none;
    transition: box-shadow 0.4s ease, outline 0.2s ease;
    appearance: none;
    border: none;
    background: top;
    padding: 0;
}

.card__rotator * {
    width: 100%;
    display: grid;
    grid-area: 1 / 1;
    border-radius: var(--radius);
    image-rendering: optimizeQuality;
    transform-style: preserve-3d;
}

.card__rotator img {
    outline: 1px solid transparent;
    aspect-ratio: 0.716;
    height: auto;
}

.card__rotator .card__front {
    opacity: 1;
    transition: opacity 0.33s ease-out;
}
```

Any advice or help would be amazing as id love to get this working!